# No photo in ImageView after return from Intent, handling life-cycle events

Tags: android, sql, android-camera, android-imageview, lifecycle

I had idea to build simple app that can store text and images. I started from Notepad Tutorial (http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html) from first and second exercise.
After I did second I arrange exercise to handle images, it was working very well unless user tapped back button in device. With help came thid exercise where the goal to handling life-cycle events. I managed to did it, it is working very well for old entries in database, but when I try to add new Image, my ImageView is not filled with just taken photo.
Can you spot where is the problem?

```
public class ParagonArmageddonEdit extends Activity
{

private EditText mTitleText;
private EditText mBodyText;
private Long mRowId;
private ImageView imageContainer;
private byte[] imageInByteArray;
private Button takePhotoButton;
private ParagonDbAdapter mDbHelper;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public boolean classEnabled;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDbHelper = new ParagonDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    setContentView(R.layout.paragonarmageddon_edit);
    setTitle(R.string.edit_note);

    this.imageContainer = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
    this.takePhotoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.photoButton);
    mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);

    Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Save);

    mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null :
        (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(ParagonDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
    if (mRowId == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(ParagonDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                                : null;
    }
    populateFields();

    this.takePhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //camera Intent
            Intent IntentKamery = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(IntentKamery, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
        }
    });

    confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }

    });
}

private void populateFields() {
    if (mRowId != null) {
        Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
        startManagingCursor(note);
        mTitleText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ParagonDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
        mBodyText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ParagonDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
        byte[] photo = note.getBlob(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ParagonDbAdapter.KEY_ZDJECIE));
        Bitmap photoConvertedToBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(zdjecie, 0, photo.length);
        this.imageContainer.setImageBitmap(photoConvertedToBitmap);
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{  
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {   
        Bitmap photoConvertedToBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageContainer.setImageBitmap(photoConvertedToBitmap);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photoConvertedToBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        imageInByteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        photoTaken = true;
    }  
}
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState();
    outState.putSerializable(ParagonDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    populateFields();
}

private void saveState() {
    String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    String body = mBodyText.getText().toString();

    imageContainer.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap photoConvertedToBitmap = imageContainer.getDrawingCache();

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photoConvertedToBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    imageInByteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    if (mRowId == null) {
        long id = mDbHelper.createNote(title, body, imageInByteArray);
        if (id > 0) {
            mRowId = id;
        }
    } else {
        mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, title, body, imageInByteArray);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Intent `android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not return a byte array in its 'data' Extra. It returns a `Uri` to the image, which must be opened e.g.

`Uri uri = data.getData();`

This provides the content path to the image, which can be loaded using a `ContentResolver`:

```
InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

You will need to ensure you check that the `Uri` exists and handle errors gracefully, you should never assume that another app is going to do something sensible, and should expect malformed/missing data wherever possible.

Comment: emmm...You must be right but in my case code for filling ImageView with photo from camera wokred very well until I implemented code for handling life-cycles.